# How to use SwatchLegend in Show?

Tags: graphics, legending

Let us suppose i have two graphs for sequences A and B as follows

```
a1 := {{0.9, 0.086133}, {0.086133, 0.0082432}, {0.0082432, 
    0.0007889}, {0.0007889, 0.0000755}, {0.0000755, 
    7.2256*10^-6}, {7.2256*10^-6, 6.9151*10^-7}, {6.9151*10^-7, 
    6.618*10^-8}, {6.618*10^-8, 6.3336*10^-9}, {6.3336*10^-9, 
    6.0615*10^-10}, {6.0615*10^-10, 5.801*10^-11}};
plot1 = ListPlot[a1, Joined -> True, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick, Dashing[{0.01}]}]
```

and

```
a2 := {{0.9, 0.21797}, {0.21797, 0.052789}, {0.052789, 
    0.012785}, {0.012785, 0.0030963}, {0.0030963, 
    0.0007499}, {0.0007499, 0.00018162}, {0.00018162, 
    0.000043985}, {0.000043985, 0.000010653}, {0.000010653, 
    2.5799*10^-6}, {2.5799*10^-6, 6.24831*10^-7}};
plot2 = ListPlot[a2, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Thick}]
```

I combine both the graphs by

```
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]
```

But cant do any things with usings Legends.
I want to use Legends to show that "Red colour box"=A and "yellow colour box"=B

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [**SwatchLegend**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SwatchLegend.html) / Applications ?

Comment: @Kuba, To show at the side of graph, two boxes of colors, where "Red colour box"=A and "yellow colour box"=B

Comment: Have you followed the link and tried to use Application's example to solve your problem?

Comment: Why do you need to use `Show` here? After all, as [E.Doroskevic's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119701/764) shows, using a single `ListPlot` (or `ListLinePlot` for that) makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: You mention [`Legends`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Legends.html), but to me it simply looks like you never even looked it up? -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example

**Code**

```
ListPlot[{a, b}, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Red, Yellow}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

**Note:** `a` and `b` are your original data lists `a1` and `a2` respectively.

**Output**

[image: example]

With `SwatchLegend`

**Code**

```
ListPlot[
{a, b}, 
Joined -> True, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Yellow}, 
PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"a", "b"}]
]
```

**Output**

[image: example]

With `Show`

**Code**

```
Show[{
  ListPlot[a, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Green],
  ListPlot[b, Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]
  },
 Epilog -> Inset[Panel @ SwatchLegend[{Green, Red}, {"a", "b"}], {0.2, .01}]
 ]
```

**Output**

[image: example output]

Comment: title: "How to use SwatchLegend in Show?"

Comment: response: "You don't. You use `PlotLegends` or `Legended`".

Comment: While it might be the case that OP can re-run the code and use single `ListPlot`, it may also be that it was heavy calculation and OP wants to use  already generated plots and add legend with `Show`, like stated in a qustion.

Comment: Wouldn't it mean the data is already available if he uses `ListPlot` anyway?

Comment: Yes, it may be so, but it also may be that he provided it to create a minimal example. As I said, OP has to clarify :)

Comment: I agree, it would be useful if author could provide more information. I have covered `Show` configuration in my last edit in case of what

Comment: @Kuba Is there really a good reason for using `Show` with `ListPlot` as the only type of plot used, if you are plotting in the same range? I struggle to think of one...

Comment: @gwr question doesn't have to be reasonable to be a valid one :) Here's an example, you don't have data anymore yet you've DumpSaved a plot, you want to combine this with something.

Comment: @E.Doroskevic your use of `Epilog` and `Inset` are unnecessary. I would use [gwr's method](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119720/52), and if I needed a different placement, I'd wrap `SwatchLegend` in [`Placed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html).

Comment: I like @gwr 's  answer as well. It shows a better way how to apply `SwatchLegend` to `Show` +1

Answer (score 7):

Actually the answer is already given in the documentation for [`SwatchLegend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SwatchLegend.html). All you need to do is to wrap [`Legended`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html) around the `Show`:

```
Legended[
  Show[ plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All ],
  SwatchLegend[ {Red, Yellow}, {"A", "B"} ]
]
```

[image: SwatchLegend]

Note: Should the legend become larger and is entered by hand, using `Transpose` may make this easier, e.g.

```
SwatchLegend @@ Transpose @ { {Red, "A"}, {Yellow, "B"} }
```

**Update:** By wrapping [`Placed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Placed.html) around `SwatchLegend[ ... ]` you can control placement.

Comment: Also, you might want to mention the use of `Placed` if the user needs the legend somewhere else.

Comment: @rcollyer So you want me to rewrite the documentation for `Legended`? :)

Comment: Sure. Include it all. (yes, sarcasm.) Mostly, it could just be mentioned with a link to the `Placed` docs.

Comment: @rcollyer You actually made me do it. :)

Comment: Ha! With a few more edits the world will be mine!!! :D

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating the legend separately and combine with `Grid`.

```
Grid[{{Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All], 
       SwatchLegend[{Red, Yellow}, {"plot1", "plot2"}]}}]
```

[image]